# Unicode encoding / decoding error in Free Pascal 3.2.0

Tags: unicode, utf-8, freepascal, string-conversion

This test passed with Free Pascal 3.0.4. (source file encoding is UTF8, OS is Windows 10 64 Bit)

```
{$MODE DELPHI}
... 
var
  Raw: RawByteString;
  Actual: string;
begin
  Raw := UTF8Encode('关于汉语');

  Actual := string (UTF8Decode(Raw));

  CheckEquals('关于汉语', Actual); 
end
```

With Free Pascal 3.2.0 it fails:

```
expected: <关于汉语> but was: <å³äºæ±è¯­>
```

RawByteString is declared as type AnsiString(CP_NONE) in system.h

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use `UTF8String` instead of `RawByteString`? And `UnicodeString` instead of `string`? Remember, `string` is still ANSI by default, unless you put the compiler into Unicode mode. What if you remove the `UTF8Encode`/`UTF8Decode` functions?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will try this (currently I have little time) and create an issue in the Free Pascal bug tracker as it worked in FPC 3.0.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion works if I cast (or declare) the characters as UnicodeString. The following test succeeds with Free Pascal 3.2.0:

```
procedure TFreePascalTests.TestUTF8Encode;
const
  THE_CHARACTERS: UnicodeString = '关于汉语';
var
  Raw: UTF8String;
  Actual: UnicodeString;
begin
  Raw := UTF8Encode(THE_CHARACTERS);
  Actual := UTF8Decode(Raw);
  CheckEquals(THE_CHARACTERS, Actual);
end;
```

The Raw variable may be defined as RawByteString or Utf8String.